# lua - calling a function from a string

Tags: lua

From what I've read on this site the below should work.
Can some kindly soul please point out where I'm going wrong?

I've embedded more description and print returns in the code hopefully to make easier reading

```
local m = {
 {opt = "Solar Panels", cmd = "solarPanel"}
     -- There are many more options here.
}  

function doTheMenu()
 print("Welcome to Spyder's Factory")
 print("")
 print("What would you like to make?")
 local n = 1
 local l = #m - 1
 while true do             --This while loop may or may not be relevant to the question, it's the menu
 term.clear()              --this is ComputerCraft lua, the term function is defined
 term.setCursorPos(1,2)    --elsewhere in an API
  for i, j in pairs(m) do
   if i == n then
    if i < 10 then print(i, "  ["..j.opt.."]") else  print(i, " ["..j.opt.."]") end
     fsel = j.cmd          --set fsel to the function name I require in case of a break
     tsel = j.opt          --Ditto, tsel, human-friendly name
   else
    if i < 10 then print(i, "   "..j.opt) else  print(i, "  "..j.opt) end
   end
  end
  local a, b = os.pullEvent("key") 
  if b == 200 and n > 1 then n = n - 1 end
  if b == 208 and n <= l then n = n + 1 end 
  if b == 28 then break end
 end
 write("\nSure, how many "..tsel.."? ")
 qty = tonumber(read())
 req[fsel] = req[fsel] + qty
 str = fsel.."("..qty..")"
 print("Loading function '"..fsel.."("..qty..")'") --Returns "Loading function 'solarPanel(1)'"
 func = loadstring(str)
 print(func)      --Returns "function: 2cdfc5a7"
 print("Loading function")
 func()  --The error line, Returns "string:1: attempt to call nil"
 --tellUserWhatNeed()
 --makeItHappen()
end

doTheMenu()
```

The issue is the code fails to run with the error:

```
string:1 attempt to call nil
```

Comment: What are you getting wrong? (btw, You can skip the cheers, the signature at the end of a post is considered bad practice)

Comment: It means that there's no global function named `solarPanel`. By the way, please try to post the minimum amount of code that exhibits the error. There's no need to show the user input stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

Also what is `term` variable, if that's all your code, `term` is not defined and is `null`)

That said: either `_G[fsel]` is `nil` or `fsel` is `nil` ?

Are you sure you have function declared in _G with the name stored in fsel?

e.i. call before the problem line `print (_G[fsel])` to see what it gives you.

Comment: term is part of a built-in API to display code to manage a ComputerCraft terminal. and the doTheMenu() line is further down. Sorry I'm unclear in my original post. I'll clear that up now

Comment: debug if you have debugger, put a couple of prints around where you think might be the problems. What are the errors? (e.g. what says `print("Loading function '"..fsel.."("..qty..")'")`)

Comment: there we go, the question should actually make sense now. The print line reads Loading function 'solarPanel(1)'

Comment: I've just done a 'print (_G[fsel])' and it returned a blank line

Comment: It should return `function: <some-address>`. The function  you are trying to call is not global (is not in _G). Are you sure you are calling `doTheMenu()` after declaring `solarPanel` ?

Comment: Using a slightly different method to call the string now, but this should also be working

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that ended up working:

```
local f = loadstring(str)
if f then
 setfenv(f, getfenv())
 f()
end
```

This replaces the lines above:

```
print("Loading function '"..fsel.."("..qty..")'") 
func = loadstring(str)
print(func)    
print("Loading function")
func()
```

As well as adding basic error handling for loading the function